# Entity Framework и SqLite: создать БД программно

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework

Как программно создать БД? Пробовал функцию CreateIfNotExists, но она возвращает false. Файл создается, но он 0 байт и при вызове функции SaveChanges возникает ошибка: "SQL logic error or missing database no such table: MyEntities". Т.е. очевидно что подключение есть, но просто не создана БД. Конфиг такой:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="Data Source=(model1.db);Version=3" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework 6(точнее провайдер) не умеет создавать базу SQLite. Увы и ах. Единственный вариант, это создавать базу отдельно, а потом уже с ней работать.

Насколько мне известно, EF7 имеет поддержку SQLite из коробки, но состояние самого EF7 мне не известно

Comment: тогда хотя бы как ее вообще создать то? Я имею ввиду что если бы речь шла о MS SQL то я бы просто открыл Management Studio и создал запросом. Но как быть с SQLite? У нее есть какие то подобные графические оболочки? Как ее создать то если не программно?

Comment: @DarkByte, [вот](http://sqlitestudio.pl) посмотрите, ещё вроде есть add-on для firefox

Comment: Ладно пофиг. Я вроде создал... Она не хотела автоматически таблицу создавать, но ExecuteSqlCommand работала нормально и я просто создал ее запросом из кода. После этого уже созданная она работает вроде нормально.

Comment: возник еще такой вопрос: как проверить существует ли таблица? Прежде чем создавать ее.

Comment: @DarkByte, используйте «create if not exists»

Comment: во первых я уже говорил что он не помогает, во вторых мне нужно проверить именно наличие таблицы, потому что БД у меня вполне себе создается автоматически как я понял, но она создается 0 байт файл без таблицы при создании объекта контейнера-наследника DbContect, поэтому мне надо проверить есть ли в ней таблица и если нет, то создать ее запросом.

Comment: @DarkByte, создавайте новый вопрос, где пишите какой SQL используете для создания и что Вас в нём не устраивает.

Comment: ок, ловите: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519468. Надеюсь на вашу помощь! :)