# Entity Framework и SqLite: проверить существование таблицы в БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, entity-framework

В продолжение [темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519347). Еще раз уточню CreateIfNotExists не работает должным образом. Хз почему. Вон ixSci вроде говорит что она EF6 просто не умеет создавать БД SQLite. Ну ок, во первых БД у меня все таки создается, но 0 байт и без таблиц, во вторых так или иначе у меня вполне работает функция ExecuteSqlCommand, поэтому я вполне могу создавать таблицы запросом. Вопрос лишь в том как проверить существуют ли они? Я придумал только вот такой примитивный способ.

```
static bool CreateIfNotExists(Model1 m)
{
    try
    {
        m.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("create table [MyEntities] (Id integer primary key not null, Name char(100) not null)");
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну я же Вам говорил, используйте `create if not exists` — это SQL, а не часть EF.

Comment: @ixSci в смысле??? Я не знаю такой SQL конструкции и EF кажется тоже не знает. Если я вас правильно понял вы имеет ввиду что то такое? "create if not exists table [MyEntities]..." На это мне пишет такую ошибку: "SQL logic error or missing database
near "if": syntax error".

Comment: EF использует не SQL, а какой-то свой подъязык, который внутри транслируется в SQL. SQLite понимает такую команду, EF, может и нет, я не силён в этом. Мой Вам совет, создайте базу в любом доступном редакторе и не пытайтесь этого делать через EF(это я только о SQLite говорю)

Comment: @ixSci но что программа будет делать если ее запустить там где нет базы???

Comment: База будет, Вы её создадите в редакторе, а уже из программы Вы будете обращаться к готовой базе, где все таблицы уже созданы и их нужно только заполнять и опрашивать. Другим решением будет отказ от SQLite в пользу, к примеру, SQL Server Compact. В перспективе, это не удачный выбор, я полагаю, но я не знаю что за программу Вы пишите и что лучше выбрать

Comment: @ixSci что за SQL Server Compact? Мне важно чтобы все что необходимо было в программе. Т.е. меня тем и не устроил обычный MS SQL что нужен обязательно запущенный на компьютере. Я в принципе не против и что то другое использовать, главное чтобы не нужно было ничего дополнительно установленного на компьютере. Пишу диплом, который запускать надо на универских компах где не установлен MS SQL Server.

Comment: Есть еще SQL Server 2014(2016) Express LocalDB - возможно подойдет тебе больше.

Comment: Не обижайтесь, но Вас в гугле забанили что-ли? Первая же ссылка в поиске Вам расскажет, что это такое. Если вкратце, то это альтернатива SQLite — ничего устанавливать Вам так же не придётся. Но SQL CE работает с EF из коробки,— EF умеет создавать базу и делать миграции.

Comment: Окей спасибо я подумаю над сменой БД на одну из этих... Я просто слышал про этот SQLite, а про те не слышал.